# Jxbrowser input type color and popup

Tags: javascript, popup, jxbrowser

I'm working on an application using Jxbrowser.
Everything work perfectly but when I try to use popups I'm having some problems.
Example 1:

```
<input class="form-control" type="color" ng-model="job.color"/>
```

When I click on my button nothing happens (I should have the color panel popup). I can open my application on web browser too and it works:

[image]

Another example:

```
var del = confirm("some text");
```

This time popup opens but I have only that:

[image]

As you can see I cannot confirm !
Here again on web browser it works:

[image]

I think it's a problem from popups/size, has some one an idea how to solve it ?

(JxBrowser 6.1)

Comment: Support of HTML input elements with the "color" type was implemented in JxBrowser 6.2. I didn't manage to reproduce the issue with a confirm dialog though. I recommend that you upgrade to the latest 6.17 version that contains a lot of fixes and improvements and check whether both of these issues are reproducible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. The problem is the project I am working on is really huge and the version used is 6.1.1, I don't think we are able to update our version because it will certainly crash our project ? Or can we update all our project to 6.2 without any change ?

Comment: The only change in the public API in JxBrowser 6.2 is related to printing to PDF. The following [migration guide](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000044779-migrating-from-6-1-1-to-6-2) describes this change.